# Is it possible to use PHP frameworks for websites built on Joomla!?

Tags: php, symfony, joomla, laravel, content-management-system

I am wondering whether I can use **PHP frameworks** such as Symfony2 or Laravel with a CMS like **Joomla**. I have worked with PHP, but a beginner of Joomla. I know I can use extensions like [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051). But I would like to use Laravel of Symfony2 instead. For example if I am developing a website where there is a considerable amount of server-side programming and also a lot of web pages to display, could I use Joomla to handle the content management and a PHP framework for the server-side programming?

---

***In brief my question is :***

**Is there any way to integrate a PHP framework(preferably Laravel or Symfony) into a website built on Joomla! ?**

If it is not capable of doing, what are the other options available; or is it not recommended to use PHP frameworks along with Joomla?

Comment: Using symfony, you could simply delegate (as in *passthrough*) *some* urls to be handled by the cms, and the rest will be handled by your symfony-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible, to integrate your framework into a CMS - so your managers or reporters or whatever, can change content. But that would be **horrible** amount of work. Better use Content management systems on their own.

It is possible to use Symfony2 with the CMS RedKite. An "Extension - CMS" for it.

More information under:

http://redkite-labs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So is it better not to use CMSs for websites involving a lot of custom PHP scripts to handle server side scripting? for example for websites like social networks, is it not a good idea to integrate a CMS to manage resources?

Comment: Sorry! I have just read this now. You can add your custom PHP scripts into the CMS. See it like that: You got 3 different things you can use.

1. Librarys
2. Frameworks
3. CMS |

Libraries have its use for 1 specific thing. Frameworks are a solution for big websites if you wanna work object oriented. the CMS is the solution-for-everything. It should be no problem to integrate your PHP script into almost any CMS - just google it "integrate custom php into XXX"

Comment: I just found that using (or creating our own) Joomla extension to handle the desired behavior of PHP is possible with Joomla..Thanks again..Now everything seems to be cleared out :)

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. Joomla is build with its own *framework* and API.

As of Laravel you could give https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator a try. It's a sweet CMS for your own models. I love this, since it's not restricting your coding and you can work with your back-end code.

If you're looking for a more client-friendly solution, http://octobercms.com/ is in the works and should hopefully be released soon.

Comment: "It's not possible" is a pretty definitive statement ... "it's not going to prove efficient" or "it's better to do something else" is a lot mroe accurate, though in fact tons of people use external frameworks along with the Joomla framework.

Comment: go ahead and put 2 complete different applications together with their own booting, autoloading, routing, ...impossible might be a strong word, but no sane soul would be trying such a thing.

Comment: I just am saying "it's no possible" is an overstatement, and all of these frameworks are attempting to have mix and match packages. Whether that works or no is a different matter, but an absolute statement it is ... too absolute. In fact for example people in the Joomla world like the Symfony session implementation a lot.